# Customizing DataTables with WEB API OData service for filtering EF - column search not working

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, datatables, odata

I am using DataTables on the client side and ASP.NET WEB API OData queryable service on the server side. The issue with sorting and filtering DataTable columns on the server side is that DataTables are generating that awful super long request with all columns info, even when they are not used for sorting or filtering. I've decided to write custom AJAX call from client to server to create neat odata query, that can be applied easily to EF context. Unfortunately column searching fields have stopped rendering as a inputs. What can be the issue?

JavaScript and HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = new Object();
  options.searching = true;
  options.searchable = true;
  options.aoColumns = [{
    "sName": "USER_NAME",
    "searchable": true
  }];
  options.bProcessing = true;
  options.bServerSide = true;
  options.sAjaxSource = "http://localhost/api/list";
  options.fnServerData = function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    var filter = "$top=5"; //just as example
    $.getJSON(sSource, filter, function(json) {
      fnCallback(json);
    });
  }
  $('#myTable').dataTable(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        First Name
      </th>
      ...

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>
        First Name
      </th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

The service works fine, and looks like this (I've made this code as easy to understand as possible).
C# code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage List(ODataQueryOptions<User> options)
{
    var result = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(_context.Users) as IEnumerable<User>;
    JQueryJsonResponse jsonUserResult = new JQueryJsonResponse
    {
        Draw = xxx,
        iTotalRecords = xxx,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = xxx,
        aaData = result.ToList()
    };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonUserResult);
}
```

I would expect something like this: 
[image: expected rendering]
But I get this: 
[image]

Comment: Your code is missing part where you add individual column filtering similar to [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), DataTables doesn't provide this feature by default. Therefore I didn't address this issue in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31883157/3549014). Also do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: That's true, but I remove that part on purpose, so it wouldn't overcomplicate the code. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

You have server-side processing mode enabled with `options.bServerSide = true;`. In server-side processing mode filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to handle parameters sent by the client on the server and perform filtering, paging and sorting. See [full list of parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) sent in server-side processing mode.

Alternative solution is to disable server-side processing mode with `options.bServerSide = false;` and let DataTables perform filtering, paging and sorting on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the question is not well formed, sorry. What I meant, that I want to apply column search to my datatables. During the copy-paste phase from other table I just missed some lines of code.
I've added something like this, and now it's working!

```js
// Setup 'Search'
var filterSelector = '#myTable' + ' tfoot th';
$(filterSelector).each(function() {
  var searchbox = $(this);
  searchbox.html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />');
});

//Apply DataTables
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable(options);

$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");

// Apply generic search
table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;
  var thatFooter = $('input', this.footer());
  thatFooter.on('keyup change', function() {
    that.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```